# Sum for every row in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query, which shows our items, which store and bin contains the item.

```
SELECT
o.ItemCode,...,i.OnHand, i.IsCommited, i.OnOrder

FROM [dbo].[OITM] as o

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[OITW] as i
ON o.ItemCode=i.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[OBIN] as b
ON i.DftBinAbs = b.AbsEntry

WHERE
i.DftBinAbs IS NOT NULL
```

One result row:

```
90245   XYITEM AV1-14-7 db          KÖZ-BAL-A-02-01 10  1   3
```

Meaning: On the KÖZ-BAL-A-02-01 bin, which stores the XYITEM items, we have 10 in store, 1 to be sold/commited and 3 already ordered items.So far so good, but I would like to also list all the items that is in the other warehouses and bins. The OITM table contains the ITEMS, OITW the warehouses and the OBIN is the bins in the warehouses. Right now it lists the items multiple times per warehouse and per bins, but that's not a problem. I need to see a sum of the item for every row.
Like if:

```
90245   XYITEM AV1-14-7 db      KÖZ-BAL-A-02-01 10  1   3
90245   XYITEM AV1-14-7 db      KÖZ-BAL-A-02-02 3   1   0
```

is the result, I would like this instead:

```
90245   XYITEM AV1-14-7 db      KÖZ-BAL-A-02-01 10  1   3 13 2 3
90245   XYITEM AV1-14-7 db      KÖZ-BAL-A-02-02 3   1   0 13 2 3
```

so it sums up based on the OnHand, IsCommited and OnOrder fields.

13 because: 10+3, 2 : 1+1 and 3 : 3+0

**EDIT**:

I connect the `OITW` table to the `OBIN` table through `OITW.DftBinAbs = OBIN.AbsEntry`, but most of the time, the `OITW` table looks like this:

```
ItemCode    DftBinAbs   OnHand  IsCommited  OnOrder
23668       NULL        50      0           0
23668       57          0       0           0
23668       NULL        0       0           0
23668       NULL        0       0           0
```

The query I got in the answers, returns one row of `23668`, that is okay, because only one row contains a `DftBinAbs` connection, but the TotalSum's are all 0 when I would like them to be for OnHand: 50 + 0 + 0 + 0, IsComited: 0, OnOrder: 0

The problem is: I want to count the `i.DftBinAbs = NULL` rows in the Total's, but hide from the result. If I use the solution from Tom H:

```
SELECT
    O.ItemCode,
    I.OnHand,
    I.IsCommitted,
    I.OnOrder,
    SUM(I.OnHand) OVER (PARTITION BY O.ItemCode) AS TotalOnHand,
    SUM(I.IsCommitted) OVER (PARTITION BY O.ItemCode) AS TotalCommitted,
    SUM(I.OnOrder) OVER (PARTITION BY O.ItemCode) AS TotalOnOrder
FROM
    dbo.OITM O
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OITW I ON I.ItemCode = O.ItemCode
INNER JOIN dbo.OBIN B ON B.AbsEntry = I.DftBinAbs
```

It returns all the rows (8000+) and the total count is okay, If I add the

```
WHERE
i.DftBinAbs IS NOT NULL
```

condition I get 133 rows (what I want), but the Total's only contains the rows with a non null `DftBinAbs`.

Also, It is an SAP Business One Database, so there are no FK constrains or anything.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this with windowed functions:

```
SELECT
    O.ItemCode,
    I.OnHand,
    I.IsCommitted,
    I.OnOrder,
    SUM(I.OnHand) OVER (PARTITION BY O.ItemCode) AS TotalOnHand,
    SUM(I.IsCommitted) OVER (PARTITION BY O.ItemCode) AS TotalCommitted,
    SUM(I.OnOrder) OVER (PARTITION BY O.ItemCode) AS TotalOnOrder
FROM
    dbo.OITM O
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OITW I ON I.ItemCode = O.ItemCode
INNER JOIN dbo.OBIN B ON B.AbsEntry = I.DftBinAbs
```

Comment: I tried it, gives me the same result as a simple sum. Also I can"t do it over partition by i.ItemCode, gives me an error: Column 'Phoenix.dbo.OITW.ItemCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It gave you the same result, but it gave an error when you ran it? That doesn't make any sense. That error message also doesn't make any sense if you've coded it as I've shown above.

Comment: I used your query, when I got 0 result for ItemCode=23668 I mention in my edit to the post.

Comment: Sorry, I used the a WHERE i.DftBinAbs IS NOT NULL condition with your query, because I also wanted to filter out the rows where the DftBinAbs is null (otherwise your query returns the correct result, but ALL the rows), but I wanted to include the null rows in the Summing. Is this a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

do like below,all you need is a cross join..Columns are derived by me for testing purposes

```
 select 
    a,b,c,d,e,f,b.*
   from table
cross join
    (select
     sum(d) as g,sum(e) as h,sum(f) 
     as i from table)
     b
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is only sums up the current row (in your example it would be 10 1 3 and 3 1 0)

Comment: Should I do this cross join before the left joins?

Comment: After left joins or before doesnt matter ,since cross join is not dependant on result set of other

Comment: It gives the same result for every row, as a total.

Comment: Thats what you asked i believe..13 because: 10+3, 2 : 1+1 and 3 : 3+0

Comment: It gives the same result as the row's OnHand,Comited and OnOrder, so in every row: 10 1 3 10 1 3, 3 1 0 3 1 0

So it just repeats, not sums up.

Comment: Could you please edit the question with alll the data so far and your required output and how it is deviating from current answers